# Create a file in ansible inside a directory

Tags: ansible

I need to create the file `kubernetes.list` inside the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

but this directory **does not exist** - So I want ansible to create the directory and `touch` the file as well.

This is the current setup I have and it throws the error

> No such file or directory

```
    - name: create the file
      file:
        path: path=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
        state: touch
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the folder before creating the file:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: create folder if not exists
      become: true
      file:
        path: /etc/apt/sources.list.d
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0775

    - name: create file
      become: true
      file:
        path: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
        state: touch
```